# Mongodb index getting deleted automatically

Tags: mongodb, quarkus, kogito

Tried to create unique index using liquibase and with compass. In both the cases index is getting deleted and we are able to insert duplicate records.
Do anyone has any information regarding this?

Comment: there will be some reasons in my opinion, 1, someone may be deleted it unexpected, 2, the indexes may be using expiration time, so please check where its applied. 3. i maybe wrong

Comment: There's not enough information here to assist. I'd suggest checking the logs to see which user account is issuing the drop command

Comment: Hi! Do you have any kind of reproducer? It's hard to tell only based on your question.